# Activity missing data on return

Tags: android

So I have my main activity which holds a list view and has a map which holds all my data for the list. Upon clicking on an item you are taken to a details display. When I press the back button to get back to the main activity from the detail activity, if I set a break point, my map keys are still intact, but all the strings in the objects are "" and the ints are -1. Here is what my main activity looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Map<String, Stunt> stunts = new LinkedHashMap<String, Stunt>();
    private StuntsDao stuntsDao;
    private ListAdapter listAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        stuntsDao = new StuntsDao(getApplicationContext());     

        stunts = stuntsDao.getAllStunts();

        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_layout, new ArrayList<Stunt>(stunts.values()));
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String stuntName = (String)((ViewHolder)view.getTag()).stuntName.getText();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StuntDetails.class);
                getStuntDetailsIfNeeded(stuntName);
                Stunt stunt = stunts.get(stuntName);
                myIntent.putExtra("STUNT", stunt);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }
...

}
```

Why would the objects in my map be basically empty?

Comment: Could it have something to do with that onCreate() doesn't get called when you click back?

Comment: Well thats what i considered so i implemented the onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState methods and it didnt help. But yeah, the onRestoreInstanceSave and onCreate methods do not get called upon return.

Comment: Those methods are for when orientation changes.

Answer (score 1):

onCreate() doesn't get called when you click back. You need to init your data again in onStart or onResume. See: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Comment: is there no way to save my map so i dont have to get it from the database again?

Comment: Well there are ways. See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html But I think SQLite is probably the best way.

Comment: You could extend your own Application class to store the data there for testing purposes, but it's a code smell: your app might run out of memory. Implementing a good DB is probably what you want.

Comment: And don't forget that data fetching should probably be done in a separate thread, like an AsyncTask.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Ill do that.